# Creating a shell script with config to run basic commands ssh connection with output

Tags: bash, scripting, ssh

I'm looking at creating a small shell script with a config file where I can set the IPs of the servers that need to checked and execute a few simple commands like who, date, uname, etc. and print the output in a file.

**UPDATE**

This is what I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=xxx
HOSTS="localhost localhost"
SCRIPT="uname -a; who; who -b; date; df -h; id"

for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
        echo "${HOSTS}" >> output.log
        ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}" >> output.log
        echo "" >> output.log
        echo "" >> output.log
done
```

Any way I can provide the appropiate host IP addres/hostname on the output? Currently it'll print all the line HOSTS, therefore showing localhost localhost on every output initialization.

Comment: I'm also hoping someone could give me a hand on how to auto enter password for the servers if possible.

Answer (score 0):

create ssh keys on all the remote servers - for the user (you) on the local server:

```
for node in server1 server2 server3
do
    ssh $node  "uname -a && who"
done
```

Or for a bunch of commands:

```
for node in server1 server2 server3
do
    echo "$node"
    for cmd in 'who'  'ls *.pdf' 
    do
        ssh $node  "$cmd"
    done
done
```